# Python 3 - Find missed tuple ranges

Tags: python, algorithm, tuples, range

Let's say I have some int range starts from 0 and ends at 48.

How can I find missed inclusive sequence from given arrays?

```
Given: [(10, 12), (12, 37)] 
Output: [(0,10),(37,48)]


Given: [(9, 15)] 
Output: [(0,9),(15,48)]


Given: [(0, 15), (15, 17), (17, 19), (21,25)] 
Output: [(19,21),(25,48)]


Given: [(23, 35),(40,47)] 
Output: [(0,23),(35,40),(47,48)]
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. what have you tried? show some code

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to ask a question according to the [ask] page. We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is on-topic here by visiting the [help/on-topic]; **asking us to write the program for you**, suggestions, and external links are **off-topic**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just iterate over the list and keep track of start and stop values this can be done fairly cleanly with the follow assuming the list is sorted. You just add a tuple to the result if the current tuple[0] is greater than the start value. You'll check at the end if you have any left over values (if `start < stop`).

```
def getMissing(l, start, stop):
    newList = []
    for tup in l:
        if tup[0] > start:
            newList.append((start, tup[0]))
        start = tup[1]
    # add any left over values
    if start < stop:
        newList.append((start, stop))
    return newList

getMissing([(2, 12), (15, 46)], 0, 48)
# result: [(0, 2), (12, 15), (46, 48)]
```

Answer (score 3):

We only need to iterate over the *sorted* tuple range, finding the missing items between the `i` position in the list, and the `i+1` position.

The first and last tuples are edge cases and need to be considered separately, as well as the empty input case. Here's a possible algorithm:

```
def find_missing_ranges(tuples, start=0, end=48):
    # edge case: empty input
    if not tuples:
        return [(start, end)]
    ans = []
    # sort the input
    lst = sorted(tuples)
    # edge case: handle start of range
    if lst[0][0] != 0:
        ans.append((start, lst[0][0]))
    for i in range(len(lst) - 1):
        # normal case, find holes between tuples i and i+1
        if lst[i][1] != lst[i + 1][0]:
            ans.append((lst[i][1], lst[i + 1][0]))
    # edge case: handle end of range
    if lst[-1][1] != end:
        ans.append((lst[-1][1], end))
    return ans
```

It works as expected with the sample input:

```
find_missing_ranges([])
=> [(0, 48)]

find_missing_ranges([(0, 48)])
=> []

find_missing_ranges([(10, 12), (12, 37)])
=> [(0, 10), (37, 48)]

find_missing_ranges([(9, 15)])
=> [(0, 9), (15, 48)]

find_missing_ranges([(0, 15), (15, 17), (17, 19), (21, 25)])
=> [(19, 21), (25, 48)]

find_missing_ranges([(23, 35), (40, 47)])
=> [(0, 23), (35, 40), (47, 48)]
```

Comment: Ah, yes, I see.

Comment: I appreciate time you spent! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple method by going through each tuple and checking if the first element is greater than the last largest element we have seen:

```
def get_gaps(tuples,l,r):
    """Return list of tuples representing gaps between l and r not covered by ranges in tuples."""

    # make sure tuples are sorted on first element
    tuples.sort()
    a= []

    for tup in tuples:
        if tup[0] > l:
            a.append((l,tup[0]))
        # update left marker to last seen (largest) element
        l = tup[1]

    # check final element of final tuple
    if r > l:
        a.append((l,r))

    return a
```

Note: this method assumes tuples do not overlap and may not produce correct results for e.g. `((10, 20),(13,16))`

Comment: They won't! Thank you for your help!